# reading and sending long message files to server C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to write a program that will read up to N bytes at a time from a file, store that in a buffer, and send that buffer to a server. This will repeat until all bytes have been read.

My problem is that it successfully sends the first N bytes, but for the remaining X bytes it overwrites up to X bytes of the original N bytes and sends that along to the server, so that the total bytes received at the end of the program are 2*N instead of N+X.

For example if I have a message and reads N bytes (in this example reads the first three lines):
1
2
3
4

The message received by the server is:
1
2
3
4
2
3

Any help as to why this is happening is appreciated!

Relevant client code:

```
// send data
  ssize_t remaining;
  char buffer[SEND_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int count = 1;

  // do this if there are still bytes to read
  while(read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    // count = read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); 
    // char buffer[SEND_BUFFER_SIZE];

  }

  // close socket
  close(sock);
```

Relevant server code:

```
  // receive message
  char buffer[RECV_BUFFER_SIZE];
  int recv_bytes = RECV_BUFFER_SIZE; 
  int i = 1;
  int count;

  // while (1 != 2) {

    while(recv_bytes != 1) {

      recv_bytes = recv(sock, buffer, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
      fwrite(buffer, recv_bytes, 1, stdout);
      fflush(stdout);

      if (recv_bytes < RECV_BUFFER_SIZE) {
        break;
      }
      
    }
```

Comment: Don’t send sizeof(buffer), send the number of bytes read.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes this worked! Thank you!

Comment: Note that `printf("%s\n", buffer);` requires a null-terminated string to be stored in `buffer`. This is not guaranteed in your code. Even if the server will send a null terminating byte at the end, it is not guaranteed that this will be received in the first `recv` call. Therefore, it is possible that `buffer` is not null-terminated at the time of the first `printf` call.

Comment: To which the solution is `printf("%.*s", count, buffer)`, where `count` is the value returned by `read()`. You can't write correct networking code without storing that value into a variable. Your final piece of code that breaks if `(recv_bytes < RECV_BUFFER_SIZE)` doesn't make sense. That condition can occur any time.